# Mongoose: use hook/middleware to remove referenced objects (has many)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In a nodejs app using Mongoose, I have a relation *has many*: App has many AppClients.

Models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const appSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  appClients : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AppClient' }]
})

const App = mongoose.model('App', appSchema)

module.exports = App

const appClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  access_key: String,
  secret_key: String
})

const AppClient = mongoose.model('AppClient', appClientSchema)
```

The thing is that I want to remove all AppClients documents related to an App document when it is deleted.
My current code is:

```
exports.delete = async function(req, res, next) {

  const app = await App.findOne({ _id: req.params['id']}).exec()
  const listToDelete = [...app.appClients]

  await App.deleteOne({ _id: req.params['id']}).exec()
  await AppClient.remove({_id: {$in: listToDelete}}).exec()

  res.redirect('/apps')
}
```

This works but I was wondering how to use a hook. I have taken a look at the [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) but I cannot make it work with the pre('remove'), it is never called. I was using something like this:

```
appSchema.pre('remove', (next) => {
  console.log('pre remove') //never called
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove` is a [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that's specified on a schema level (like in your example) but it runs on a document level. So the only way to get this fired is to fetch the document and then execute `remove()` on it

```
const app = await App.findOne({ _id: req.params['id']}).exec();
await app.remove(); //prints 'pre remove'
```

There is a paragraph in Mongoose docs about that:

> Note: There is no query hook for remove(), only for documents. If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(), not when you call MyModel.remove(). Note: The create() function fires save() hooks.

Answer (score -1):

According [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#naming) you should be able to use the hook without finding the document in a first hand.

```
appSchema.pre('remove', { query: true }, function() {
  console.log('remove');
});
```